# Сервисы тестирования приложений

Tags: тестирование, функциональное-тестирование

Как можно протестировать поведение скрипта для **различных версий** приложения в **различных ОС**?

Можно конечно, поставить виртуальную машину, туда поставить необходимый софт и закинуть скрипт, но это долго.

Может есть какие-то сервисы для этого? Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой - как решали?

Comment: Сталкивался, ставил виртуальные машины (точнее докер по больше части) со всем софтом и скрипты.

Comment: @user7860670, значит, единственный выход - это виртуалка... Жаль. =(